# Logging a variable in Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I would like to log a session variable in my Heroku log (so that I can read it using `heroku log` in my console).

Do I need to config anything? How should I go about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works.  This would be in your controller after you set the variable.

```
logger.info "#{session_variable}"
```

If it's an ActiveRecord you could use to_yaml or inspect.  Even puts I think outputs stuff onto the heroku logs.

Tweak that to your needs.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html